# Elasticsearch query to parameterise to avoid max_compilations_per_minute error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-percolate

I want the below Elasticsearch query to parameterize because sometimes I am getting an error like this.

> [script] Too many dynamic script compilations within one minute, max:
>   [15/min]; please use on-disk, indexed, or scripts with parameters
>   instead; this limit can be changed by the
>   [script.max_compilations_per_minute]

If we go for index script or file-based script will it help to remove this error?

```
 {
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "query_string": {
                  "query": "a*",
                  "quote_analyzer": "standard",
                  "allow_leading_wildcard": "true",
                  "analyze_wildcard": "true",
                  "default_operator": "AND",
                  "phrase_slop": 1
               }
            },
            {
               "script": {
                  "script": {
                     "source": "Pattern p =  /\\s?a\\S*?/i;   p.matcher(params._source.summary ?: '').find();",
                     "lang": "painless"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I do not want to update or increase script.max_compilations_per_minute because it's CPU intensive.

I tried few option with index or file base script but no success.